# Calculated column - SQL - Football Teams

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I'd like to add a new second column to a 'teams' table which is representative of premier league (UK) football rankings. At the moment the table just contains the names of each football team.

The column will be called 'Played' and it will list the number of games each team has played. I'd like to calculate this number (integer data type) from a separate table called 'games', which records a historic log of games fixtures. This would probably include using SQL's native 'COUNT' function.

I have tried to use a function to help me do this, but currently it is inserting all values as '0'

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPlayed](@Team VARCHAR)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
   RETURN(SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM games
   WHERE games.Home = @Team OR games.Away = @Team);
END;

ALTER TABLE teams
ADD Played AS GetPlayed(teams.Team)
```

The tables:

teams:

````
```Team
Arsenal
Bournemouth
Burnley
Chelsea
Crystal Palace
Everton
Hull City
Leicester City
Liverpool
Manchester City
Manchester United
Middlesbrough
Southampton
Stoke City
Sunderland
Swansea City
Tottenham Hotspur
Wat"For"d
West Bromwich Albion
West Ham United
```
````

games:

```
gameID  Home    HomeScore   Away    AwayScore   GameDate
4   Arsenal 2   Chelsea 0   2018-05-26
5   Arsenal 5   Bournemouth 0   2018-04-22
6   Arsenal 1   Leicester City  1   2018-03-15
7   Bournemouth 5   Liverpool   0   2018-04-22
8   Burnley 5   Bournemouth 0   2018-04-22
9   Burnley 1   Swansea City    2   2017-11-22
10  Stoke City  0   Burnley 0   2018-01-08
11  Chelsea 1   Middlesborough  2   2017-11-22
12  Southampton 0   Chelsea 0   2018-01-01
13  Crystal Palace  1   Everton 2   2018-03-26
14  Manchester United   4   Crystal Palace  0   2018-06-01
15  Crystal Palace  0   Southampton 1   2018-04-16
16  Everton 1   Hull City   2   2017-11-20
17  Manchester City 4   Everton 0   2017-11-20
18  Hull City   0   Burnley 0   2018-06-01
19  Sunderland  2   Hull City   0   2018-06-15
20  Leicester City  3   Tottenham Hotspur   1   2017-09-20
21  Swansea City    2   Leicester City  5   2018-02-15
22  Sunderland  0   Leicester City  1   2018-01-29
23  Liverpool   3   Tottenham Hotspur   0   2018-02-28
24  Stoke City  1   Liverpool   2   2017-09-19
25  Manchester City 2   Manchester United   4   2018-05-02
26  Middlesborough  1   Southampton 1   2018-02-08
27  Stoke City  2   Middlesborough  2   2017-08-19
28  Swansea City    0   Manchester United   5   2018-06-27
29  Sunderland  1   Tottenham Hotspur   2   2017-09-01
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks, Rob

Comment: I'd suggest using a `VIEW` and include the column in there. Use a `CROSS APPLY` or `GROUP BY` to return the data, not your function or a sub query in your `SELECT` statement. Scalar functions aren't the best performers, and neither are sub queries in the `SELECT`, as they are run once per row, rather than once for the dataset.

Comment: Yeah this is a calculated value, not something that should be stored. You should calculate it when you need it.

Comment: VARCHAR without size defaults to 1

Comment: @Steve has absolutely pointed out the issue. Of course he is correct that a parameter defaults to 1, but a column defaults to 30. This is why you should ALWAYS specify the size. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: To be specific, a parameter declared as `varchar` defaults to a `varchar(1)`, however, a `CAST`/`CONVERT` with `varchar` as it's input parameter defaults to `varchar(30)`. For example `SELECT CONVERT(varchar,'1234567890123456789012345678901234567890');` returns `123456789012345678901234567890`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VARCHAR without size defaults to 1 char, you need to change your function declaration

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPlayed](@Team VARCHAR(32))
.....
```

Without size your parameter *@Team* will receive just the first letter of your passed team value and, of course, the WHERE statement is unable to find any result in your games table